# Entity Framework Code First Table-Per-Type Inheritance include base type

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, table-per-type

I have the following model (overly simplified)

```
public class Training
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Training Training { get; set; }
}

[Table("Students")]
public class Student : Person
{
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
}
[Table("Instructors")]
public class Instructor : Person
{
    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }
    public IList<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to query the database using a training name:

```
var training = _trainingRepository.FindByName("training class 1", include => include.Persons);
```

This queries the database and includes all the Student and Instructor.

**Question:**

Let's say I have a person that is neither a student or an instructor but he is part of "training class 1".
I would like to know if it is possible to also get said person in the list of Persons and if so how?

**Update**

The real reason why I am asking the question is because I have 39 distinct derived class and the query built by EF is *really* slow for obvious reasons. I am trying to get with the initial query only the few most common cases and will get the other cases individually afterward if necessary with a `IN` (EF Contains) using the base class.

**Answer**

The answer was to remove the "abstract" keyword from the Base class (Person).

Comment: any reason for the downvote? this seems like a perfectly valid question to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to remove the abstract keyword from the Base class (Person):

**FROM:**

```
    public abstract class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Training Training { get; set; }
    }
```

**TO:**

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Training Training { get; set; }
    }
```